# Numpy Kronecker delta Matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I want to build an M by M matrix where each cell_{ij} is a function of the Kronecker delta &_{ij}

Here is the code for doing this using a for loop:

```
# Note: X is an M by M numpy array
def build_matrix(X):
   def kd(i, j):
     if i==j:
         return 1
     else :
         return 0

  m = np.zeros((len(X), len(X)))
  for row in range(len(X)):
      for column in range(len(X)):
          m[row][column] = kd(X[row], X[column])
  return m
```

Is there a better - more pythonic - way of achieving this?

Comment: [np.eye](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html)

Comment: numpy.eye returns an identity matrix,  the function above doesnt always return an idneitity matrix.   it takes the value of X[row_index] and X[colom_index] and returns one if they are equal

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to compare two vectors then an option is to use `np.meshgrid` to broadcast an `n` vector to an `n x n` matrix. `np.meshgrid(x,x)` will return two matrices: the first with the vector stacked in rows, the second in columns. See the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) for more info.

Then you can define the function as:

```
def kronecker_matrix(x,y):
  kmat = np.meshgrid(x,x)[0] == np.meshgrid(y,y)[1]
  return kmat.astype(np.int)   #kmat is a boolean, with .astype you pass it to an integer, if you like

#example:
kronecker_matrix(np.arange(5), np.arange(5))
>>array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

you could map each value in your matrix to prime numbers:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(5, size=(5,5))
b = np.random.randint(5, size=(5,5))
print(a)
 
 ([[4, 1, 3, 4, 2],
   [1, 2, 2, 3, 0],
   [3, 1, 4, 4, 4],
   [2, 0, 4, 4, 1],
   [3, 2, 1, 3, 0]])

print(b)

 ([[4, 4, 0, 3, 2],
   [3, 1, 3, 4, 4],
   [0, 3, 2, 2, 0],
   [3, 2, 4, 4, 3],
   [0, 0, 3, 1, 2]])
```

in this case, the only numbers that aren't prime numbers are 4 and 0, so we will change 4 to 5:

```
a[a==4]=5
b[b==4]=5
```

and 0 to 7:

```
a[a==0]=7
b[b==0]=7
```

then:
print(a)

```
 ([[5, 1, 3, 5, 2],
   [1, 2, 2, 3, 7],
   [3, 1, 5, 5, 5],
   [2, 7, 5, 5, 1],
   [3, 2, 1, 3, 7]])

print(b)

 ([[5, 5, 7, 3, 2],
   [3, 1, 3, 5, 5],
   [7, 3, 2, 2, 7],
   [3, 2, 5, 5, 3],
   [7, 7, 3, 1, 2]])

mat = a*b
print(mat)

 ([[25,  5, 21, 15,  4],
   [ 3,  2,  6, 15, 35],
   [21,  3, 10, 10, 35],
   [ 6, 14, 25, 25,  3],
   [21, 14,  3,  3, 14]])

mat_sq = np.sqrt(mat)
mat_sq[mat_sq == mat_sq.astype(int)] = 1
mat_sq[mat_sq != mat_sq.astype(int)] = 0
print(mat_sq)

 [[1. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```